# Spring Cloud Stream @SendTo Annotation not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream with Spring Boot. My application is very simple:

ExampleService.class:

```
@EnableBinding(Processor1.class)
@Service
public class ExampleService {

    @StreamListener(Processor1.INPUT)
    @SendTo(Processor1.OUTPUT)
    public String dequeue(String message){
        System.out.println("New message: " + message);
        return message;
    }

    @SendTo(Processor1.OUTPUT)
    public String queue(String message){
        return message;
    }
}
```

Procesor1.class:

```
public interface Processor1 {

    String INPUT = "input1";
    String OUTPUT = "output1";

    @Input(Processor1.INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel input1();

    @Output(Processor1.OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel output1();
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.destination=test_input
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.group=test_group
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.binder=binder1

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output1.destination=test_output
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output1.binder=binder1

spring.cloud.stream.binders.binder1.type=rabbit
```

spring.cloud.stream.binders.binder1.environment.spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost

Scenarios:

1) When I push a message in 'test_input.test_group' queue, message is correctly printed and correctly sent to 'test_output' exchange. So ExampleService::dequeue works well.

2) When I invoke ExampleService::queue method (from outside the class, in a test), message is never sent to 'test_output' exchange.

I'm working with Spring Boot 2.0.6.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Stream 2.0.2.RELEASE.

Anybody knows why scenario 2) is not working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What leads you to believe that `@SendTo` on its own is supported? `@SendTo` is a secondary annotation used by many projects, not just Spring Cloud Stream; as far as I know, there is nothing that will look for it on its own.

Try Spring Integration's `@Publisher` annotation instead (with `@EnablePublisher`).

**EDIT**

To force proxying with CGLIB instead of a JDK proxy, you can do this...

```
@Bean
public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor bfpp() {
    return bf -> {
        bf.getBean(IntegrationContextUtils.PUBLISHER_ANNOTATION_POSTPROCESSOR_NAME,
                PublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class).setProxyTargetClass(true);
    };
}
```

Comment: It makes A LOT of sense having a Spring Cloud Stream annotation doing that, why only cover the cases of 1) listening a message from a stream and 2) redirect a message from one stream to another and not the case of creating a message in a stream?

Comment: Perhaps, but why duplicate existing capabilities; after all, `MessageChannel` based spring-cloud-stream apps are based on the Spring Integration foundation. Most Spring projects build on some existing foundation. Again, if there is some documentation that leads you to the conclusion that it should work, open a GitHub issue to either fix the documentation or make a solid case that it should be supported.

Comment: FYI using Publisher it's being a pain in the neck because it doesn't support proxies like StreamListener (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150939/spring-cloud-stream-and-publisher-annotation-compatiblity/54151130?noredirect=1#comment95135190_54151130)

Comment: I fixed the work around to avoid early bean initialization.