# Spring Cloud Stream and @Publisher annotation compatiblity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Since Spring Cloud Stream has not an annotation for sending a new message to a stream (@SendTo only works when @StreamListener is declared), I tried to use Spring Integration annotation for that purpose, that is @Publisher.

Because @Publisher takes a channel and @EnableBinding annotations of Spring Cloud Stream can bind an output channel using @Output annotation, I tried to mix them in the following way:

```
@EnableBinding(MessageSource.class)
@Service
public class ExampleService {

    @Publisher(channel = MessageSource.OUTPUT)
    public String sendMessage(String message){
        return message;
    }
}
```

Also, I declared @EnablePublisher annotation in a configuration file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnablePublisher("")
public class ExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ExampleServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ExampleService exampleService;

    @Test
    public void testQueue(){
        exampleService.queue("Hi!");
        System.out.println("Ready!");
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.ExampleServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'exampleService'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'exampleService' is expected to be of type 'com.example.ExampleService' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86'
```

Problem here is that ExampleService bean can not be injected.

Anyone knows how can I make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use a `@Publisher` annotation in your `ExampleService`, it is proxied for that publishing stuff.

Only the way to overcome the issue is to expose an interface for your `ExampleService` and inject already that one into your test class:

```
public interface ExampleServiceInterface {

     String sendMessage(String message);

}

...

public class ExampleService implements ExampleServiceInterface {

...


@Autowired
private ExampleServiceInterface exampleService;
```

On the other hand it looks like your `ExampleService.sendMessage()` does nothing with the message, so you may consider to use a `@MessagingGateway` on some interface instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway

Comment: Several things: 1) But, for example, when using Cacheable annotation in a service method, that makes a proxy from the service too, but I can inject that proxied service without any problem declaring EnableCaching(proxyTargetClass = true). Maybe there is something like EnableIntegration(proxyTargetClass = true). It's really annoying to duplicate all the service classes using Publisher 2) I read about MessageGateway and it's interesting to have an injectable gateway, but I like the idea of Publisher because it works like an aspect. In the other way I have to explicitly call gateway.sendMessage()

Comment: Well, there is the way, like declare your own `PublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` static bean with the `setProxyTargetClass(true)` instead of the `@EnablePublisher`. But I indeed agree with your that we need to add such a `proxyTargetClass` attribute into the `@EnablePublsiher` annotation. Please, raise an issue and contribution is welcome: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues !

Comment: The issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2695

Comment: Hi, I raised an issue here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2695, but I got stuck with your temporary solution. Can I reuse the implementation of PublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor and only change that flag? I can add another question in Stack overflow if you want.

Comment: Well, that was my point. You create a bean for the `PublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`  and set its `setProxyTargetClass()` to `true`.

Comment: Until the annotation is fixed, I added a work around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119209/spring-cloud-stream-sendto-annotation-not-working/54119620#54119620).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just send the message to a stream manually, like below.

```
@Component
@Configuration
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class Sender {

    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;

    public void send(String message) {

        processor.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());

    }

}
```

You can test it through the tester.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class SenderTest {

    @Autowired
    private MessageCollector messageCollector;

    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;

    @Autowired
    private Sender sender;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    public void testSend() throws Exception{

        sender.send("Hi!");
        Message<String> message = (Message<String>) this.messageCollector.forChannel(this.processor.output()).poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        String messageData = message.getPayload().toString();
        System.out.println(messageData);

    }

}
```

You should see "Hi!" in the console.