# Spring Cloud Stream: @StreamListener processing messages twice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream (Edgware.SR5) with Spring Boot (1.5.10.RELEASE). My @StreamListener is processing twice every message it receives.

The idea of the example is to publish a message in a queue and the process it.

Service:

```
@EnableBinding(ExampleBindings.class)
@Service
public class ExampleService {

    @Publisher(channel = ExampleBindings.OUTPUT)
    public String queue(String message){
        return message;
    }

    @StreamListener(ExampleBindings.INPUT)
    public void dequeue(String message){
        System.out.println("New message: " + message);
    }
}
```

Bindings:

```
public interface ExampleBindings {

    String INPUT = "input1";
    String OUTPUT = "output1";

    @Input(ExampleBindings.INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel input();

    @Output(ExampleBindings.OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel output();
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.default.group=group1
spring.cloud.stream.default.binder=binder1

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.destination=dest_1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output1.destination=dest_1

spring.cloud.stream.binders.binder1.type=rabbit
spring.cloud.stream.binders.binder1.environment.spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
```

Configuration (for injecting proxied service in the test):

```
@Configuration
public class ExampleConfig {

    @Bean
    public PublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor publisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(){
         PublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor publisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor =
            new PublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
        publisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(true);
        return publisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ExampleServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ExampleService exampleService;

    @Test
    public void testQueue() throws InterruptedException {
        exampleService.queue("Hello!");
        Thread.sleep(1000);//Wait for message processing
        System.out.println("Ready!");
    }
}
```

I'm having the following output:

```
17:19:10.230 [dest1.group1-2] DEBUG o.s.c.s.b.StreamListenerMessageHandler - org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler@575c3e9b received message: GenericMessage [payload=Hello!, headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=dest1, amqp_receivedExchange=dest1, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=dest1.group1, amqp_redelivered=false, id=2f22ce16-bb5a-350c-8b3d-e6c898760888, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-sxu6zQHJTGrsazfwbmol9Q, contentType=text/plain, timestamp=1547583550230}]
New message: Hello!
17:19:10.231 [dest1.group1-1] DEBUG o.s.c.s.b.StreamListenerMessageHandler - handler 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler@575c3e9b' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=Hello!, headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=dest1, amqp_receivedExchange=dest1, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=dest1.group1, amqp_redelivered=false, id=788e8bbf-4ae4-86cc-0859-d4f153cb5807, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-fV0aaDzYUZfq08JsODq6pA, contentType=text/plain, timestamp=1547583550230}]
17:19:10.231 [dest1.group1-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'input1', message: GenericMessage [payload=Hello!, headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=dest1, amqp_receivedExchange=dest1, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=dest1.group1, amqp_redelivered=false, id=788e8bbf-4ae4-86cc-0859-d4f153cb5807, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-fV0aaDzYUZfq08JsODq6pA, contentType=text/plain, timestamp=1547583550230}]
New message: Hello!
17:19:10.232 [dest1.group1-2] DEBUG o.s.c.s.b.StreamListenerMessageHandler - handler 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler@575c3e9b' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=Hello!, headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=dest1, amqp_receivedExchange=dest1, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=dest1.group1, amqp_redelivered=false, id=2f22ce16-bb5a-350c-8b3d-e6c898760888, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-sxu6zQHJTGrsazfwbmol9Q, contentType=text/plain, timestamp=1547583550230}]
17:19:10.232 [dest1.group1-2] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'input1', message: GenericMessage [payload=Hello!, headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=dest1, amqp_receivedExchange=dest1, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=dest1.group1, amqp_redelivered=false, id=2f22ce16-bb5a-350c-8b3d-e6c898760888, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-sxu6zQHJTGrsazfwbmol9Q, contentType=text/plain, timestamp=1547583550230}]
Ready!
```

I can't figure out what is the problem with my configuration or if it is some bug, any advice?

Thanks!

EDITED:

I uploaded a (non) working example [here](https://github.com/italktothewind/spring-cloud-examples)

You can create a RabbitMQ instance using:

```
docker run -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Comment: You show `Processor` for `input1`/`output1`, but I see in logs `input2`. Does it say anything to you?

Comment: I have edited manually the logs because I don't want to expose business logic, I will edit it.

Comment: Now it's edited.

Comment: OK. May we have some simple sample somewhere on GitHub to play with? Thanks

Comment: Those messages are not the same. The content may be the same, but `id`, `amqp_consumerTag` etc are all different. So, indeed post a reproducible sample somewhere (you can exclude the business logic)

Comment: I have uploaded this repository: https://github.com/italktothewind/spring-cloud-examples , thanks!

Comment: Also, are you sure your queue is empty before you run the test?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted docker (docker run -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management) so queues were empty before tests run.

Comment: I found the problem, thanks, it was because of the workaround in the configuration class for having injectable services using @Publisher.

Comment: right, i was just going to say remove the @Bean for post processor and simply use `@EnablePublisher("defaultChannel")`

Comment: With that you have a lot going on there, lots of redundant configuration as well as you are not using the testing framework for spring-cloud-stream. Perhaps you should revisit/refactor

Comment: Unfortunately, @EnablePublisher is not enough to have an injectable service: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150939/spring-cloud-stream-and-publisher-annotation-compatiblity/54151130?noredirect=1#comment95135190_54151130

Comment: It is enough. I just modified your example. . .

Comment: If you remove the Bean configuration you will have this exception: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @StreamListener method 'dequeue' found on bean target class 'ExampleService', but not found in any interface(s) for bean JDK proxy. Either pull the method up to an interface or switch to subclass (CGLIB) proxies by setting proxy-target-class/proxyTargetClass attribute to 'true'

Comment: Please execute mvn clean install (it re-runs the test)

Comment: As I said, I have your example working with `@EnablePublisher` and Bean configuration removed

Comment: I tried to add EnablePublisher and remove the bean configuration and exception still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I detected that @Publisher was publishing twice because of the configuration in ExampleConfig. This new configuration (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119209/spring-cloud-stream-sendto-annotation-not-working/54119620)) seems to work fine:

```
@Bean
public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor bfpp() {
    return bf -> bf.getBean(IntegrationContextUtils.PUBLISHER_ANNOTATION_POSTPROCESSOR_NAME,
        PublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class).setProxyTargetClass(true);
}
```

Comment: you don't need `setProxyTargetClass(true)`

Comment: If I remove that Bean configuration I have this stacktrace:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @StreamListener method 'dequeue' found on bean target class 'ExampleService', but not found in any interface(s) for bean JDK proxy. Either pull the method up to an interface or switch to subclass (CGLIB) proxies by setting proxy-target-class/proxyTargetClass attribute to 'true'

Comment: Another answer to this issue is an explicit bean name for your `PublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and it is this one: `IntegrationContextUtils.PUBLISHER_ANNOTATION_POSTPROCESSOR_NAME`. The problem that Framework still creates a default one. So, you class is proxied really twice.

Answer (score 1):

From the config, I think, you are trying to publish the same message again to the same destination `dest_1`.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.destination=dest_1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output1.destination=dest_1
```

And from the log it is clear, the 2nd message has a different ID

```
id=788e8bbf-4ae4-86cc-0859-d4f153cb5807
id=2f22ce16-bb5a-350c-8b3d-e6c898760888
```

Comment: I think that input1 is dest_1.group1 queue and output is dest_1 exchange.

Comment: Yes, indeed they were different ids because they were published twice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was running my application in debug mode(intellij) due to which somehow the offset wasn't getting updated. Try running on run mode and it solved my problem.